# Where is the official definition of 'bind' and 'return' for the Writer Monad in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, writer-monad

So far I have found:

```
http://monads.haskell.cz/html/writermonad.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)
```

which give definitions for `>>=` and `return`

Where is the official code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Monad` instances for the standard transformers are found in the `transformers` package. For `WriterT`, look [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html#line-124). Unfortunately, at the moment there's not good tool support for finding where a particular instance is defined -- you just have to do some educated guesswork (or be clever with your favorite `grep` replacement).

Comment: Great - that's it.  I'm just learning the details of individual monads so having been going directly to their files - haven't looked into the `transformers` package yet --- looks like I need to put that on my TODO list.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW: your link had `#line-124`.   Is there some way to get those anchors besides manually inspecting the HTML source?

Comment: @haroldcarr Well, there's only a few different kinds of anchors haddock produces, and it's possible to know them all. I'm not claiming I do, but here's a handful of useful ones: `#v:name` for the place that defines the value `name`; `#t:name` for the place that defines the type `name`; and `#line-n` for the line `n`. Since instances don't define a new value or type, you have to use the `#line` form (and hence figure out the line number somehow), but the other two are more predictable.

Comment: I see that in the HTML source.  I was hoping for some magic!  Very useful info - thanks!

Comment: BTW @daniel-wagner: now that I understand there is no magic, thanks for taking the time to dig out the line number in your original response!

Answer (score 0):

All source can be found on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/src/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html).

Comment: Yes, I've been there.  For example: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html --- but I am having a hard time finding `bind` and `return` - thus the request for help.

Comment: That is because the 2.x versions of `mtl` take the concrete implementations from `transformers` (note the `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Lazy` import in the source). On its own, `mtl` just adds monad classes such as `MonadWriter`.

Comment: @duplode Mind if I steal your comment and use it as an answer?

Comment: @Tarrasch Not at all, feel free to do it.